# Capture and forward extended PKI cert attributes (e.g. UPN) using haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy, openssl, pki

I'm trying to pull an attribute from a client certificate in a mutual authentication scenario and set it as a HTTP header in the request to backend. See `fig 1` below.

```
fig1
  [user with correct certificate]
                 |
                 | 1. presents cert with normal v1 attributes
                 | has additional "extension" attributes
                 | incl. "Subject Alt Name" which contains
                 | "User Principal Name" ( UPN looks like an email addr) 
                 |
     [example.com:443 haproxy] --app1 / app2 CNAMEd to example.com 
                 |
                 | 2. read Subject Alternative Name
                 | 3. regex or parse out UPN
                 | 4. set REMOTE_USER header to be UPN
                 | 5. pass to backend(s)
                 |
       ┌------------------┬
       |                  |   
       |                  |   
       |                  |   
       |                  |   
       V                  V                 
 [app1svr:80]       [app2svr:80]
```

Normally, it's easy, you would just pull the attribute you want using the built in functionality like so:

```
frontend https
 bind *:443 name https ssl crt ./server.pem ca-file ./ca.crt verify required

 http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-DN        %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn]
 http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-CN        %{+Q}[ssl_c_s_dn(cn)]
 http-request set-header X-SSL-Issuer           %{+Q}[ssl_c_i_dn]
 http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-NotBefore %{+Q}[ssl_c_notbefore]
 http-request set-header X-SSL-Client-NotAfter  %{+Q}[ssl_c_notafter]

 default_backend app1svr

backend app1svr
 server app1 app1svr.example.com:80

backend app2svr
 server app2 app2svr.example.com:80
```

List of attributes here: https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.3.4

Unfortunately, missing from the list of attributes are any of the COMMON extension attributes such as:

- Subject alternative name

  - RFC822 Name
  - Other Name

    - Principal Name
- CRL Distribution Points

I can't seem to figure out the right way to access these attributes.  Looking at the code (below line 5815) https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/blob/master/src/ssl_sock.c it doesn't seem to be *just* a documentation issue.

Any thoughts here?
(possibly related issue): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966461/reading-an-othername-value-from-a-subjectaltname-certificate-extension

Comment: I don't see it, either.  If you don't get a helpful answer here, I'd suggest taking this to the [project mailing list](http://www.haproxy.org/#tact) as a question, followed by a feature request.  It seems reasonable enough to me, but I'm not the one who has to write it, so that's easy enough to say. :)

Comment: Not looking good for the mailing list, no messages archived for all of 2016 `http://marc.info/?l=haproxy`...will try it tomorrow if no one has any ideas. Community site has very light traffic `http://discourse.haproxy.org/`, may have to take it to github

Comment: The archive is third-party, and broken.  The mailing list itself is very much alive.  I've found a couple of bugs in 1.6 and 1.7 and they have been resolved promptly, on the list.  It's used developer communications, patch review, bug tracking, help-I'm-stuck, and feature requests.

Comment: OK submitted, bad timing, but it's out there.  We'll see if the mailing list kicks it back since there are a couple links in it.

Comment: No one seems to care about smart card / PIV.  Ended up just using Apache 2.4-20 -- Works fine, would rather have used ha-proxy.

Answer (score 1):

As HAProxy version 1.5.14 (see http://www.haproxy.org/news.html) HAProxy send the whole certificate in the ssl_c_der attribute.

So, if you put the following lines in haproxy configuration file

```
http-request set-header X-SSL-ClientCert-Base64          %{+Q}[ssl_c_der,base64]
```

then you could read the whole client certificate by reading the X-SSL-ClientCert-Base64 header.

Comment: Yeah, that is fairly well documented.  Not quite what I need because I can't edit how authorization is done on the remote server.